# Prove that $f(x)=x^2 \sin\left ( \frac{1}{x} \right )$ for $x \neq 0$, $f(0)=0$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis

How to I prove this?? The questions asks "Observe this function is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$."

Comment: HINT: the derivative is defined on all R except 0. On 0, calculate the limit by definition.

Comment: @LeeNeverGup Thanks for your comment. But I think I get how to prove this is differentialble at 0. The problem is at all points except 0.

Comment: @eChung00: do you know that $\frac{1}{x}$, $\sin$, $x^2$ are all differentiable (for $\frac{1}{x}$, outside $0$)?

Answer (score 4):

It suffices to show (*using the definition of the derivative)* that

$$\lim_{x\to0}x\sin\left(\frac1 x\right)=0$$
since the $\sin$ function is bounded.

**Added** The fact that $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R^*$ is clear so let's show that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ which's equivalent to show that
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0}x\sin\left(\frac1 x\right)\ \text{exists}$$

Comment: I need more detail!!

Comment: @eChung00 I edited my answer.